# Java Print - How to set paper size and orientation attributes

Tags: java, file, pdf, printing, attributes

I need to print a PDF and configure the paper size and orientation.
This is my code, but the attributes are not working.

```
private void doPrint(){
    try{

        PDDocument aImprimir = PDDocument.load(new File("./file.pdf")); //org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attributes.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A8);
        attributes.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);

        PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); //javax.print.PrintService & javax.print.PrintServiceLookup

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); //java.awt.print.PrinterJob

        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(aImprimir));
        job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
        job.print(attributes);
        aImprimir.close();
    }
    catch(DocumentException | PrinterException | IOException | NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Error" + e):
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `PDDocument`, `PrintService` and `PrinterJob` ? If they aren't your classes, post imports or source code if they are.

Comment: @CrazySabbath code edited with imports

Comment: It would seem, that default implementation ignores attribute set.

Comment: Why don't you try using non default service, example: `PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attributes)[0];`

Comment: This code only find my PDFCreator printer

Comment: What do you mean your PDFCreator? Post some code?

Comment: I mean that with the arguments, paper size ISO_A8 and orientation portrait, the lookupPrintServices only find one printer, (I have 5 printers), and it's not the printer I like to use.

I deleted the paper size attribute and finds the correct printer. But ignores the PORTRAIT argument.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but for future references, I add my findings to it anyway:

I found [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing2d.fm1.html) stating:

> The PageFormat specification also overlaps with the Java Print Service Media, MediaPrintableArea, and OrientationRequested attributes. If an application uses the Printable interface and the print(PrintRequestAttributeSet) method, the media, orientation, and imageable area attributes contained in the attribute set are added to a new PageFormat, which is passed to the print method of the Printable object. If an application uses the Pageable interface, the PageFormat does not change.

Thus, your call to `job.print(attributes);` ignores your specific/additional `attributes`. Instead, you either have to modify your `Pageable` object in a way such that your `attributes` are added to its `PageFormat` (e. g. using a modifying wrapper/delegator), or you have to set up your `Pageable` instance to incorporate these attributes in the first place.

I'm still experimenting on my own and cannot confirm this is working - but the approach looks promising to me.